# What's the maximum file-name length of an audio file in telegram?

Tags: telegram

I have a bot that downloads videos from youtube and converts it to mp3, After that, the audio file is sent to the user.

However, I have noticed that if the filename[.mp3] exceeds a certain limit, Telegram discards the name, and replaces it with "Unknown File".

Tl;Dr: What's the maximum file-name length of an audio file in Telegram?

Comment: Windows only allows file and folder names of 260 characters or less. Good idea to trim larger names in your bot.

Comment: 260 character, but not UTF-8 character, just a normal char.